# Object is not iterable when setting generic relation

Tags: django

I'm trying to set my generic relation in Model A:

```
class A(models.Model):
    relation = GenericRelation('B')
    another_relation = GenericRelation('B')

class B(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    content = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Yet when I try to do:

```
relation = B.objects.get(pk=1)
model = A(relation=relation).save()
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: 'B' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GenericRelation is the *reverse* side of the relationship. As with a normal ForeignKey, there are potentially many items that link to any particular instance of B.

You'd need to do:

```
relation = B.objects.get(pk=1)
relation.content = A().save()
relation.save()
```

Comment: Now here's a weird situation, I'm having two fields on my model with generic relations to the same generic model. So how does it know which field is which object?

Comment: I don't think the distinction is at all meaningful. As I said, GenericRelation is not actually a field, it doesn't store anything on the A model itself. It's just the reverse accessor for the generic foreign key on B. So both GenericRelations on A would point to the exact same set of B instances.